# How to install torch in alpine

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, dockerfile, alpine-linux

When I tried to install torch in alpine, it report there is no version distribution found for it.

```
FROM alpine:3.18
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip3 install torch # <-- report: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
```

Comment: Alpine is unlikely to work, because it [uses musl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818831/is-there-a-best-practice-on-setting-up-glibc-on-docker-alpine-linux-base-image) which doesn't have [pthread_attr_setaffinity_np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740411/cannot-import-pytorch-in-alpine-docker-container) (and possibly other members of glibc that Torch might need). If you are dead-set on using Alpine, you could try upgrading [this image](https://github.com/petronetto/pytorch-alpine/blob/master/Dockerfile) (and check that user's repos for the base images)

Comment: @ZacAnger Thanks for the update. This would make a good answer, you should add it!

Answer (score 1):

Alpine is unlikely to work, because it [uses musl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818831/is-there-a-best-practice-on-setting-up-glibc-on-docker-alpine-linux-base-image) which doesn't have [pthread_attr_setaffinity_np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740411/cannot-import-pytorch-in-alpine-docker-container) (and possibly other members of glibc that Torch might need). If you are dead-set on using Alpine, you could try upgrading [this image](https://github.com/petronetto/pytorch-alpine/blob/master/Dockerfile) (and check that user's repos for the base images). But it would be more straightforward to just start with [one of the PyTorch images](https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch).

Comment: +1 @ZacAnger "pthread_attr_setaffinity_np" isn't even a part of glibc.  It's in libgomp.  The conclusion i've arrived at for now, is that you'd just keep having to GNU libraries to the point that your container/system would be GNU ( not alpine )

Comment: @scrypted thanks for the clarification, yeah, that's not in glibc itself. It's probably possible to patch it into Alpine's version of gcc/libgomp, but also probably not worth the effort when Pytorch already has official images.